# Why is there a slow delay in segue

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue

I have read the other segue delay articles and they don't give enough information.

I am segue'ing to a view with the following UIImageView (background), and 15 buttons. There is a big delay in the transition (on iPhone 4) could this be because of the amount of buttons?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is more likely to take time to load. Loading fifteen buttons takes virtually no time, even on an original iPhone.

Comment: It also depends on how high resolution the image is.